# Does harming a companion indirectly with Warding Bond affect their approval?

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

If one of my companions casts
[Warding Bond](https://baldursgate3.wiki.fextralife.com/Warding+Bond)
on my main character, and therefore takes damage whenever "I" do, does
harming them in that way cause their approval to decrease?

I would think not, since the caster should understand how their own
spell works, but Shadowheart often (maybe half the time?) complains
about the redirected damage as if it was intentional, asking for
example, "Did you do that on purpose?!".

Example screenshot of the combat log (Tav is my main character):

[image: Shadowheart: Did you do that on purpose?!]

Is her approval dropping because of that?

I can't tell from the in-game approval display because it
is just a meter with no number, making it very hard to notice small
changes.

I've done some searching but it's been difficult to avoid spoilers.  For
example, I haven't read the entire Warding Bond article linked above
because it quickly descends into "OP strats", etc., which I don't want
to see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some experimentation, I conclude that **no**, harming companions
indirectly with Warding Bond does not affect their approval.  They
complain, but the complaints are inconsequential.

First, I'll note that the approval *is* available as a number, just in a
different part of the UI than where I was looking.  Specifically, in the
"details" tab, it's near the bottom:

[image: Numeric approval on details tab]

Checking this number after each action, I discovered:

- Direct damage *does* affect approval.  If my main character hits
  Shadowheart with three melee attacks (even fists), she will lower her
  approval by 10, and a message "Shadowheart disapproves" appears
  briefly in the center of the screen (not in the corner like for
  dialogue).  Missed attacks have no effect on approval.
- Complaint dialogue lines ("Watch it, oaf!") have no connection to
  approval.  Any time she takes damage or is attacked (even on a miss)
  and attributes the source of damage to my character, she has about a
  25% chance to speak a complaint line.  (I didn't test with other
  companions doing damage.)
- Damaging her indirectly with Warding Bond never affects approval,
  regardless of whether the damage is environmental or from an attack, and
  regardless of whether the damage incapacitates her.